# Does a Monero desktop ticker exist?

Tags: exchange, trading-volume

I would like a desktop ticker so I don't have to go to a webpage constantly to check the Monero price in BTC.

I found one at https://www.coingecko.com/en/widgets/ticker/monero/btc but I have no idea how to put it on my desktop, it says "copy and paste to where you want it" but it does not copy to desktop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "official" Monero desktop ticker but there is a Monero Monitor [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/monero-monitor/ojekadcfnkkihlleaafggfgbggdckpgo/) add on and available [source code](https://github.com/Monero-Monitor/monero-monitor) from community member bigreddmachine and a [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bitcoin-price-ticker/) add on mentioned on the same [HelloMonero](https://hellomonero.com/article/get-date-monero-pricing-info-these-chrome-and-firefox-addons) page.

The CoinGecko ticker you linked to is meant to create website or blog widgets not your desktop:

> Looking for a cryptocurrency price widget which includes major digital currencies like Bitcoin, Litecoin, Dogecoin, Darkcoin, and more? CoinGecko has a price ticker widget that you can embed for free into your website/blog.

You did not mention if you use a Windows, Apple or Linux PC. There are methods to convert web widgets into [desktop widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=desktop+widget) which can be found on Stack Overflow.

If you are an Android user, the [CoinCap.io](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.coinCap.coinCap) app seems to have good reviews. Always be very cautious when downloading cryptocurrency apps and widgets, particularly those that are closed sources or from unknown parties.

Answer (score 12):

I struggled to find a good menubar ticker for OS X, and eventually settled on using [BitBar](https://getbitbar.com) with a small plugin I wrote. Just drop this into your BitBar plugins folder and call it `xmrrate.30s.sh` or something:

```
#!/bin/bash

# XMR BitBar ticker, by Riccardo Spagni
#
# Shows last trade value for BTC/XMR on Poloniex

XMR=$(curl -s "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker" | egrep -o '"BTC_XMR":{"id":114,"last":"[0-9]+(\.)?([0-9]{0,5})?' | sed 's/"BTC_XMR":{"id":114,"last":"//' | sed 's/"//')

echo "∙ XMR: $XMR ∙"
```

Adjust as needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a Mac, [Coin Tick (on the App Store)](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/coin-tick-crypto-ticker/id1141688067?mt=12) is pretty nice. Covers all the cryptocurrencies on coincap.io and uses their API to update.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote one!

https://github.com/johnalanwoods/XMRTicker

Got tired of Poloniex taking up the browser, so I wrote a simple app for OSX (macOS) that puts the price of XMR right on the menubar.
It's really simple and lightweight, and updates every 30 seconds.
I might add more features / pairs (against BTC for e.g.) if people like it...

Source: https://github.com/johnalanwoods/XMRTicker

Prices are sourced using the Polo API.

Comment: That's great. Before I download it though, could someone with more knowledge than me check whether it's safe to use (no offence Woodstock!) and post back?

Comment: @StrawbsUK - someone already vetted the code here, no offence taken!, https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5mqkk1/comment/dc61wyx?st=IXRASIYR&sh=19e775e3

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a **Linux** system with the **GNOME** desktop environment, you can find some useful extensions to display info on various cryptocurrencies. You can easily set these to show only the **Monero** value.

Here, my choices:

Bitcoin Markets - https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/648/bitcoin-markets/

Binance Ticker Monitor - https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1397/binance-ticker-monitor/

Krypto GNOME Extension - https://github.com/sereneblue/gnome-shell-extension-krypto